How to include text for JRadioButton in the form of dt, dd inline in java swing?
I have been trying to add 2 radio buttons which indicate Modes like A and B with a long description like shown in the below image.
I need,

the Mode names to appear in bold text
the following sentence to start in the same line
sentence to follow the format of dd (not coming below the mode name, if extended to next line).

I have tried few available suggestions online and not been successful so far. Please suggest me on how to achieve the same.
JLabel label = new JLabel();
   label.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.RIGHT);
   label.setName("LABEL NAME");
   label.setVisible(true);
    
JRadioButton modeA = new JRadioButton("<html><dl><dt><b>Mode A: </b></dt><dd>This sentence is really long and is expected to be displayed in 2 or more lines.</dd></dl></html>");
    modeA.setFocusPainted(false);
    modeA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 12,0));
    modeA.setName("Mode_A");
    modeA.setVisible(true);

JRadioButton modeB = new JRadioButton("<html><dl><dt><b>Mode B: </b></dt><dd>This sentence is another example of a long string and is expected to be displayed in 2 or more lines.</dd></dl></html>");
    modeB.setFocusPainted(false);
    modeB.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 0, 0, 0));
    modeB.setName("Mode_B");
    modeB.setVisible(true);
    
ButtonGroup grp = new ButtonGroup();
    grp.add(modeA);
    grp.add(modeB);
    
JPanel togglePanel = new JPanel();
    togglePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout (togglePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    togglePanel.add(modeA);
    togglePanel.add(modeB);
    
int hgap = 15;
int vgap = 15;
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, hGap, vGap));
    mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
    mainPanel.add(label);
    mainPanel.add(togglePanel);

Expected result is,


I have tried using CSS style to have dt and dd inline
I have tried using dfn tag

both have not worked for me.

Looks to me like a twofold radio button group in a BoxLayout

Is it an option to use <table> instead and create a 2x1 table with the mode and description?

When I ran your code, this is what your GUI looked like:

With a few modifications, this is what I came up with:

I used @Progman's suggestion and put the text in an HTML table.  And yes, I used a <br> to break the sentences into two lines.
Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JRadioButtonExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JRadioButtonExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JRadioButton Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        int hgap = 15;
        int vgap = 15;
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, hgap, vgap));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Please select either of the modes:");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        label.setName("LABEL NAME");

        String text = "<html><table><tr><td>";
        text += "Mode A:</td><td>This sentence is really long";
        text += " and is expected<br>to be displayed in 2 or more lines.";
        text += "</td></tr></table></html>";

        JRadioButton modeA = new JRadioButton(text);
        modeA.setFocusPainted(false);
        modeA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 12, 0));
        modeA.setName("Mode_A");

        text = "<html><table><tr><td>";
        text += "Mode B:</td><td>This sentence is another example of a";
        text += " long string<br>and is expected to be displayed";
        text += " in 2 or more lines.";
        text += "</td></tr></table></html>";

        JRadioButton modeB = new JRadioButton(text);
        modeB.setFocusPainted(false);
        modeB.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 0, 0, 0));
        modeB.setName("Mode_B");

        ButtonGroup grp = new ButtonGroup();
        grp.add(modeA);
        grp.add(modeB);

        JPanel togglePanel = new JPanel();
        togglePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(togglePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        togglePanel.add(modeA);
        togglePanel.add(modeB);

        mainPanel.add(label);
        mainPanel.add(togglePanel);

        return mainPanel;
    }

}


Good. Personally I think it looks more easy on the eye when each 'sentence' is preceded by <br>
